Error code "Error while fetching extensions XHR failed" in visual studio code
I am very new to coding and I accidentally deleted my live server extension, when I tried to redownload it gave me the error code "Error while fetching extensions XHR failed" I am using Mac OS Sonoma 14.4.1, I am using the visual studio code editor, and I have the "F-Secure" parental restrictions app installed, this may be unrelated but npm is giving me errors when I try to install firebase.
I have tried deleting vscode and changing my proxy setting from override to fallback, on, and off.

I don't know about F-Secure, but I'm pretty sure it could restrict network access. I'm not going to tell you how you could bypass this, but you definitely shouldn't boot to BIOS, and definitely shouldn't install a separate linux partition on your drive.  Linux is very nice for software. You should look into it if you can, and no. F-Secure cannot "Reach" Linux in any way :D. IF you're new to Linux, you should try Ubuntu or Mint
